# Install path for add-ons problems with german windows

Tags: add-on, path, installation

I can't install Add-ons
When i want to install them the path shown is C:\Users\HP\Documents
You probably say that's good
But I have German Windows (as my Laptop is bought in Germany and I'm German)
so it Should be C:\Benutzer\HP\Dokumente

Even when I want to change the path by browsing it shows the English system paths.
And they don't exists.
Typing the real existing Path doesn't help. It creates the path but doesn't create anything in it.
What's almost funny is that it created a duplicate of the path that already exists.
The only difference is its creation date (and that it's empty)

The version of blender is 2.93.1
(I had installed both 2.8 and 2.93 together on my PC before!)
And I have to mention that I am an absolute beginner to Blender.
I did a 2.8 beginner tutorial before, but I don't remember whether adding add-ons was a part of it or whether I had problems with it.

So what do I have to do (to install add-ons on my German laptop)?

Thanks
Dirk

Comment: If you install an add-on via *Preferences*, the add-on gets installed into `C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Blender\2.93\scripts\add-ons` on Windows no matter what the language is set to. Why do you think the document folder is necessary here? To answer your question: Always install add-ons via *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Install.*

Comment: @Brockmann: maybe explain a bit more to him, since he is beginner and i am pretty sure he is not aware that what he "sees" in the explorer is not the "real" path

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: so there should be something @ C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons . But there is nothing. And even when I select the non-exiting C:\Users\HP\Documents\ @ Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Install nothing is created.!?

Comment: The `AppData` folder is just hidden. Go to `C:\Users\<user>` using the explorer, append `\AppData` to the path and hit enter. Again, no document folder involved here. To proof that, install any add-on, open up the console and see where blender put it *OR* install the add-on and open up its preferences by clicking on the little triangle and see the path and it is: `C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Blender\2.93\scripts\add-ons\the-name-of-the-add-on`.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#blender-s-directory-layout